# How to ask briefly about the ownership of a frying pan?

Tags: questions, possessives

Near to my room there is a frying pan and I don't know who is the owner of this kitchen utensil. What is the correct way to ask it briefly?

1. Whose this frying pan (is this correct?)
2. Whose this frying pan belongs?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could ask:

Who owns this frying pan?

Who does this frying pan belong to?

Who is the owner of this frying pan?

Whose frying pan is this?

Comment: Or even maybe "who**m** does this frying pan belong to?" 8-O

Comment: Many people regard "whom" as hypercorrect nowadays.  But I'd say "To whom does this frying pan belong?"  rather than ending the sentence with the preposition, which  mixes registers.

Comment: Can we say "Whose this frying pan is?" I understand that the meaning is a little bit different. Would such a formulation be unusual?

Comment: It would be ungrammatical.

Comment: @pabouk "Whose is this frying pan?" is the correct word order. (it may offend some grammar purists, but it's commonly used in British English)

Comment: @alephzero: Thank you. Actually this is what I was looking for. I wanted to have the constituent "this frying pan" instead of the two constituents "frying pan" and "this". I just confused the word order in a question.

Comment: That may be a cultural/regional thing, @alephzero. As a native speaker from northeast USA, I would find that word order very awkward.

Comment: That's why I said "in British English." I suppose we both agree that "Whose is this?" (while pointing at the object) is OK. "Whose is this [name or description of something]" seems to follow the same pattern.

Answer (score 31):

"Whose frying pan is this?" is how most people would say it.

Edit--"Who does this frying pan belong to?" might be about as common. "Whom" is almost never used in spoken English. (For example, you would likely have to watch many hours of television before hearing a single "whom.")

Comment: Lest you watch period dramas.

Comment: Whom does this frying pan belong to? To whom does this frying pan belong?

Answer (score 2):

"Whom does this frying pan belong to?" seems wrong to me.

"To whom does this frying pan belong?" sounds better,

although I'd say "Whose is this frying pan?"

Comment: Nothing wrong with “Whom does this frying pan belong to?”, apart from it being a somewhat unusual combination of the presence of one trait associated with formal registers (‘whom’) and the absence of another (prepositional fronting). It’s perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I'm not sure there's "nothing wrong" with it - the vast majority of native speakers would think you very strange if you said that!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I can believe that you are technically correct. It may be perfectly grammatical, but it "seems" wrong to a native speaker (i.e. me). Actually, what one would say is probably along the lines of "Does anyone (or Do you) know whose frying pan this is?", not presupposing that ownership is known by the addressed person(s).

Comment: @J.B I wouldn’t say it seems _wrong_ as such—just uncommon. I agree completely that you’d be unlikely to hear it from a native speaker, but it’s not ungrammatical. “Nothing wrong with” may have been overstating it (makes it sound like it’s completely normal); “nothing ungrammatical about” is a better description.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, it really *is* wrong, it doesn't just seem that way. 
It suddenly came to me:
Who does this frying pan belong to?
or
To whom does this frying pan belong?

Comment: @J.B In a word: no. _Who(m)_ is the object of _to_ in both cases. In traditional grammar, where the oblique case of _who_ is supposed to be _whom_ invariably, “Who does this belong to?” would be considered ungrammatical. “Whom does this belong to?” would (most likely) be considered grammatical but plebeian, since dangling prepositions were considered Bad Form. “To whom does this belong?” would be the only uncontroversial version. Nowadays dangling prepositions are widely accepted and _whom_ is rapidly losing ground. But none of the versions is ungrammatical.

Comment: As TRomano said in the comment to his answer, “Whom does this belong to?” mixes _registers_. Dangling prepositions, while perfectly grammatical, are generally considered to belong to a lower, more colloquial register, while _whom_ belongs to a higher, more formal register. That's why they clash—because they give conflicting hints of register. But register does not make grammaticality in English.

Comment: The traditional latin-derived rule that it is incorrect to put a preposition at the end of a sentence is obsolete, but, from Oxford University Press: "In standard English the placing of a preposition at the end of a sentence is widely accepted, _provided the use sounds natural_". Which it doesn't in this case, so it's wrong. It's not just about formal grammar.

Comment: But placing the preposition at the end here does _not_ sound unnatural. Using _whom_ sounds (a bit) unnatural when you place the preposition at the end. Arguably. Personally, I don’t think it sounds unnatural, and I would not be unlikely to say “Whom does this belong to?”. It may well be unnatural to some, but not to all. But then I’ve heard native speakers claim that simple, unambiguous cases like “Whom did you see?” are incorrect, which is clearly very far from universally correct. Saying that something is _wrong_ makes it about formal grammar; this isn’t _wrong_, just not ideal.

Comment: See also the answers to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3910/prepositions-at-the-end-of-sentence-and-whom) (note that they both categorise “whom… to” as grammatical, but unlikely to be used much, which matches my own personal gut feeling).

Comment: No doubt that "whom ... to" is perfectly grammatical. But to me, and a straw poll of native speakers, it still sounds wrong, worse than "To whom ... ". I'd refer you back to the original answer I gave.

Answer (score 2):

Although the previous answers are all fine, for me it depends on the social situation and if you're asking verbally or not, the previous answers "sound" as if they are in a written context (which I guess would fit the situation in the question if you were leaving a note).

For example if you know the other person well, they are in the same room as you, and can communicate visually by raising the pan during the question I would say this, with a raising intonation at the end of the question...

"Is this your pan?"

...or if you know them really well, simply...

"Your pan?"

This may not be linguistically or grammatically perfect, but it's the way people talk "round my way" :)

Comment: Why even say pan if you're holding it up? Just "is this yours?"

Comment: Yup, that works too.